# Superscript and subscript

Tags: superscripts

I want to write a superscript and a subscript at the same place.Every time I do it, it is a superscript then a space followed by the subscript. How do I stack it vertically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal , yet complete, code illustrating the  problem?

Comment: Please also clarify what you mean by "at the same place". E.g., should the superscript and subscript terms be stacked vertically?

Comment: @Mico Yes, the superscript and the subscript are to be stacked vertically.

Comment: Are you possibly inputting things of the form `A\textsubscript{B}\textsuperscript{C}`? If so, you shouldn't. You should employ math instead of text mode and write `$A_B^C$`. Here, `$` serves to enter and exit inline math mode.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. It worked.

Answer (score 11):

I presume you are in math mode and I assume you want to have both superscript and subscript horizontally aligned next to the symbol you are super-/subscripting. You can achieve this like this: `$A_b^c$`. Note that the order is irrelevant, `$A^c_b$` looks identical. You can group symbols using curly brackets like so: `${A_b}^c$` or `$A_{b^c}$`. [image: Examples for super-/subscripting in math mode]

Comment: The last one has a typo. It should be `$A_{B^C}$ produces...` (the `_` is outside the `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks Phelype, have corrected the typo